# Convert a list of list's names(str) into a list of lists in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have search a lot about this issue. I know there is a way of converting tuples to a list, but somehow it doesn't work for me. Here is my issue.

Say I have:

```
l_1 = ['a','b','c']
l_2 = ['e','f','g']
l_3 = ['g','h','i']
```

Then say I have another list of:

```
l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']
```

How can I convert it(l_all) to a list of

```
[['a','b','c'],['e','f','g'],['g','h','i']]
```

I tried ast package using ast.literal_eval, but I received this error:

> ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at
>   0x00000172CA3C5278>

I also tried to use json package, still no luck.

I tried just output `ast.literal_eval('l_1')`, not working either.

I'd really appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you get into this situation?

Comment: Are you asking for `ls_all = [ls_1, ls_2, ls_3]`?

Comment: I don't see any tuples, what is the relation to your problem?

Comment: BTW you have a typo `1_1` => `l_1`, but you got it right afterwards, so I took the liberty of fixing it.

Comment: @cricket_007 actually it's the opposite. OP doesn't want to create variable, OP wants to _evaluate_ variables.

Comment: @StephenRauch apparently they have like more then 50 lists( like l_1 to l_50) and each list has different values. Technically I can just do [l_1, l_2,....l_50] but it looks ugly. So I used a loop to get ['l_1', 'l_2' ....'l_50'], but now its all strings not list object. yeah thats how I got myself into this lol

Comment: @kingslucifer, As you now know naming your variables `l_1`, `l_2` ... is not a good idea in Python.  Use a list or a dict instead.

Comment: @StephenRauch ohhh thanks for the reminder. I didn't name them as this haha. Just using it as example :)

Comment: >>> l_1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> l_2 = ['e','f','g']
>>> l_3 = ['g','h','i']
>>> l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']
>>> [eval(i) for i in l_all]
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I am not sure I would agree with *irrelevant*, but it may not be perfect, please feel free to reopen it

Comment: never mind. The question title sucks (and the question is not very good as well) but some of the answers address the `globals()` function, and this is solved anyway. I'm not going to pretend that this question is super-original. Leave it be :)

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like a problem that should be fixed upstream

`ast.literal_eval` evaluates *literals*. `eval` is just 1) cheating and 2) so dangerous I wouldn't recommend it at all.

Anyway, you could scan global then local variables using global & local dicts in a list comprehension:

```
l_1 = ['a','b','c']
l_2 = ['e','f','g']
l_3 = ['g','h','i']
l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']

l_all = [globals().get(x,locals().get(x)) for x in l_all]
```

result:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

`globals().get(x,locals().get(x))` is a quick & dirty code to first look in global vars & fallback to local vars if not found. It could be overcomplicated for your needs.

Comment: omg life savers!!!!! thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary to store the list names and each associated list:

```
d = {'l_2': ['e', 'f', 'g'], 'l_3': ['g', 'h', 'i'], 'l_1': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']
final_results = [d[i] for i in l_all]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

However, to actually access the lists via variable name, you would have to use `globals`:

```
l_1 = ['a','b','c']
l_2 = ['e','f','g']
l_3 = ['g','h','i']
l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']
new_l = [globals()[i] for i in l_all]
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: not my downvote. But your first version doesn't answer the question. OP has data as he posted. And also you copied the typo from OP (that I just fixed). so none of your solutions work.

Comment: can you elaborate why using `globals()` is not recommended?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre My understand of `globals()` is that accessing `globals()['something']` with new data could produce unintended output if  `'something` is actually intended to give different result, but when passed to `globals()` returns something entirely different.

Comment: you mean like `1_1 `? :)

Comment: Thanks lot!!!!! I tried this one and it works as well. But I decided to use the one from @Jean-FrançoisFabre too keep my code short. Many thanks again!

Comment: note that Ajax solution is actually shorter :)

Answer (score 1):

> Then say I have another list of:
>
> `l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']`

Let's say you don't create this using strings, and use the  list variables directly

You can then get the wanted output

```
l_all = [l_1,l_2, l_3]
```

Comment: oh, cuz i have a lot of those lists and those are defined by users. I want to keep them more organized so I used a loop to create l_all.

Comment: Okay, so something like `l_all = [user.get_list() for user in users]` would not be possible?

Comment: My point here is that "numbered variables" are a sign that you need a better design. For example, you can use a SQLite database for storing user input rather than just an in-memory list. Then you can query all rows of the database to get a list of all lists

Comment: yeah i totally agree on this. I know its dumb...this project is for my company and theres data control sigh

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
l_1 = ['a','b','c']
l_2 = ['e','f','g']
l_3 = ['g','h','i']
l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']

print(list(map(lambda x:globals()[x],l_all)))
```

output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

```
l_1 = ['a','b','c']
l_2 = ['e','f','g']
l_3 = ['g','h','i']

l_all = ['l_1', 'l_2', 'l_3']

all_local_variables = locals()
l_all_values = [all_local_variables[i] for i in l_all]
```

And you should be aware that you can get `KeyError` if no such variable present in current scope, for that you can `all_local_variables.get(i)`, that will return `None` if not present or set default as `all_local_variables.get(i, 'default')`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to evaluate your strings in l_all. Something like this

```
>>> l_1 = ['a','b','c']
>>> l_2 = ['e','f','g']
>>> l_3 = ['g','h','i']
>>> l_all = ['l_1','l_2','l_3']
>>> [ eval(x) for x in l_all ]
```

The output is

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It is the exact answer to the question! Please leave a comment if you downvote.